# Дан массив символов. Удалить символ «двоеточие» (:) и подсчитать количество удаленных символов

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

void change(char *str, int &count);
bool symbol(char *str, char ch);

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUSSIAN");

    char str[100] = "#rkt:# afet:rk: faktrlaa:etqg"; //набор символов.
    int count = 0; //счётчик элементов.

    cout << str << endl;
    change(str, count);
    cout << str << ' ' << '\n' << "Количество замен: " << count << endl;

    return 0;
}

void change(char *str, int &count)
{
    do {
        while (*str++) {
            if (*str == ':') {
                char temp = *str;
                *str = *(str + 1);
                *(str + 1) = temp;
            }
        }
    } while (*str);
}
```

Вопрос 1-ый. Как сделать так, чтобы цикл do while работал несколько раз. В моём случает происходит сдвиг на 1 элемент. Как я понимаю вместо while(*str) нужно написать что-то другое, как я понимаю while(*str) это условие. 
Вопрос 2-ой. Как подсчитать количество символов ':' в этой же функции. Переменную count объявил как ссылку, это правильно?

Comment: Может есть какая-то функция которая проверяет строку на содержание символа?

Comment: Почему бы просто не использовать _string_ и не создать новую строку?

Comment: Я хочу изменить саму строку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Простой проход по массиву. Если встречается `:` - не сохраняем этот символ, но увеличиваем счётчик. Если другой - то сохраняем, но с учётом смещения. Каждую итерации текущий символ хранится в `str[0]`, а предыдущие, получается, в отрицательных индексах.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

void change(char *str, int &count);

int main() {
    char str[100] = "#rkt:# afet:rk: faktrlaa:etqg"; //набор символов.
    int count = 0; //счётчик элементов.

    cout << str << endl;
    change(str, count);
    cout << str << ' ' << '\n' << "Количество замен: " << count << endl;

    return 0;
}

void change(char *str, int &count) {
    count = 0;
    while (*str) {
        if (str[0] == ':') {
            count++;
        } else {
            str[-count] = str[0];
        }
        str++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо работает, буду разбирать теперь как сделать через while

Comment: @Ilya можно и без for, и без константы, да. Обновил код, взгляните.

Comment: спасибо большое, для меня это привычнее